# Call subsequence within HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to call fn:subsequence within HtmlAgilityPack?
I'm trying the following:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("fn:subsequence(//table[2]//table[6]//b, 1)");
```

Which throws this exception: "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, IMO, I find `using System.Linq` for HtmlAgilityPack is more handy in this case. You can have something like:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("b").Where(_ => //you can implement some conditions here).Skip(1);
```

Well, if you are curious about this then:
fn:subsequence is part of XPATH 2.0 and currently .NET doesn't support XPATH 2.0. They are planning to support XPATH 3.0 soon.

You can vote here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4450357-implement-xslt-3-0-for-net

Comment: This works. I've tried that. But I'm really curious about subsequence. Thanks.

Comment: Now that's an answer!